# Iterate loop in Python through multiple databases in SQL

Tags: python, sql, pandas, for-loop, pymssql

Currently have a remote SQL server without multiple database structures on it. Connecting through Python code using PyMSSQL plugin and extracting data into pandas before applying some analysis. Is there a way to iterate such that with each loop, the database number changes, allowing a new database's data to be analysed?

E.g. 
*connect to server

```
cursor.execute("SELECT TOP 100 *variable name* FROM *database_1*")
```

*analyse

*disconnect server

Ideally would have a loop allowing me to automatically read data from say *database_1* through to *database_10*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can easily do this using [read_sql()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) method:

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://USER:PWD@hostname/db_name')

for i in range(1,10):
    qry = 'SELECT TOP 100 variable name FROM database_{}'.format(i)
    df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
    # analyse ...
```